# search filter pressing return key activating custom button instead of applying filters

Tags: salesforce-classic

I've got a standard Salesforce search filter and some custom buttons.
After I fill in some fields and I press enter, the first custom button is focused and executed, instead of executing the standard "apply filters" button.
Is it possible when pressing enter that the standard "apply filters" button is executed instead of the first custom button?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to prevent the default action and call the search method. Here's a typical example:

```
<apex:form id="form">
  <apex:actionFunction action="{!doSearch}" name="searchSystem" reRender="form" />
  <script>
  function searchOnEnter(event) {
    if(event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
      searchSystem();
      event.returnValue = false;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  </script>
  <div onkeypress="searchOnEnter(event)">
    <apex:inputText value="{!searchField1}" ... />
    <!-- more fields here -->
  </div>
  <!-- more code here -->
```

You might need to tweak this code slightly, as I'm going off of memory, but the general idea is that you need some JavaScript to block the default action and execute your own actionFunction in its place.

Comment: OK, thx I'm going to try this!

Comment: Hey, is it possible to add the javascript code to the standard search layout without the use of a button? cause google is not providing any answers :-p

Comment: @user37597 Doh. I missed that part, I thought this was Visualforce. Nope, you can't change the behavior of the standard UI.

Comment: ty for the quick respons!